# Android: Failing to open an activity in adjacent screen in multiwindow

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

I have two of my activities (same app) opened in multiwindow / split-screen. Now I want that when a user taps on a button on Screen-1, I want to open an activity in Screen-2.

I have read Android's document and I think I am doing it right, but it is not working. It still opens the new activity in Screen-1. Here is my code:

```
   val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
   intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   startActivity(intent)
```

I have set

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

in the manifest, under the "application" tab, also in the "activity" tag.

What wrong am I doing?

I also tried this:

```
       val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) 
       intent.data = Uri.parse(MyActivity::class.java.name)
       intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
       startActivity(intent)
```

didn't work.

Another related question I want to ask is, is FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK required? what if I don't want to create a new task?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also include:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
```

In the `or` of your intent flags.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: what Android version is the device you are trying this  ?

Comment: Android 12 (API level 31)

Comment: might it be that you are missing some permission request, or something?

Comment: no because I entered the split screen mode programmatically from the same app. So it should allow me to open Activity in adjacent screens

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is that do a **software update** on your testing device.

I also got the same situation the code is fine according to the document but it does work properly. When I try to do a software update on my testing device, that problem goes. ^^)